# How to create a Stored Procedure with dynamic Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
Create MySchema.MySpName
As
Begin
   Select * from MyTable
End
```

As you can see above there is a stored procedure in schema `MySchema`, I want to use this schema dynamically.

As I have many databases with different schemas like `MySchema1`, `MySchema2`. Suppose I want to execute my above stored procedure in schema `MySchema1` so I want that my stored procedure will be created with schema `MySchema1.MySpName`

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to create a procedure without specifying the schema and for that matter any object created in SQL Server is schema bound this is a security constraint SQL Server implemented in SQL Server 2005.

All the objects in SQL Server has to be under a specific schema. Now in your case you have two option.

1. Create this procedure in every schema in your database.
2. Create a procedure in any one schema and inside the procedure make it accept the object name and schema name.

**Example**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Proc_Name
@SchemaName NVARCHAR(128),
@TableName  NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @Sql = N' SELECT *  FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) 
             + N'.'  + QUOTENAME(@TableName) 

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Now this procedure will live under default schema but you can pass the schema name and object name at run time to call objects from different schemas.